# Is there a way to label Python code in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

We have made a few examples of code in Python and inserted them into a LaTeX/overleaf document. We are currently looking into making a label for them, so they can be referenced at various points, however using the `\begin(python)` doesn't seem to allow us to add a `\label{}`, which works and can be referenced.
A similar example of what we are looking for would be

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany,english]{book}
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}

\begin{python}\label{SO-test}
    value_a = 1                   
    value_b = 2                    
    print(value_a + value_b)     
\end{python}
```

Any tips or tricks are appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] so we can see which method you use to insert your python code?

Comment: Should have added one now. I'm still new to using Stack Overflow, so please do correct me or let me know if I need to add or change something.

Comment: Can you please make a compilable [mre] starting with a documentclass and the necessary packages? The solution might depend if you are using the listings, minted or some other package to get your python environment.

Comment: Should've been added to the question/post now. If you have any other packages or similar, we're more than happy to add them. We do however have various other packages for other things, which aren't exactly relevant.

Comment: next time, please make the code fragment compilable, e.g. add `\begin{document}` etc. It is really so boring to type those things for the millionth time.

Answer (score 4):

Behind the scenes the `pythonhighlight` uses the much more common `listings` package. The listings package allows you to add a caption and label as optional argument of the `lstlistings` environment.

However even though the `pythonhighlight` sets up its `python` environment with the possibility to add an optional argument, it never uses this argument. Thus the information is never forwarded to the `lstlistings` environment.

To work around this, you can set up your own environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany,english]{book}
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}

\lstnewenvironment{mypython}[1][]{\lstset{style=mypython,#1}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{mypython}[caption={some text to produce a caption},label=SO-test]
    value_a = 1                   
    value_b = 2                    
    print(value_a + value_b)     
\end{mypython}

Reference: \ref{SO-test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I tried to just include this in a comment, but I'm too new to stack overflow.

Have you tried just using regular verbatim instead of making it explicitly python?  Is there something wrong with that?

```
\begin{verbatim}
Text enclosed inside \texttt{verbatim} environment 
is printed directly 
and all \LaTeX{} commands are ignored.
\end{verbatim}
```

I also saw this thing about minted in their library.

It makes a reference to \begin{minted}{python}

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_Highlighting_with_minted

Comment: Sadly ```\begin{verbatim}``` doesn't allow for the use of ```\label```, which is what we're using most of the time, to reference figures, graphs, etc.